# How to get all DbSet from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to get all tables in the database using EF. I need them to go table by table and extract certain information from each. Any idea how?

Comment: You need to get all DbSet or all tables? You question with the title is not clear.

Comment: The DbSet is the same that tables.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you use EF, depending on the size of your database, could take a very long time to execute.

Comment: I need to iterate each table or DbSet in DbContext to extract information from each of the tables in the database

Comment: Why? Can you explain what information you need to get out of each table and what you plan to do with it, when you say certain data how is that data being filtered? You should be able to iterate the DBSets without too much issue, I just cant think why you would want to.

Comment: I'm trying to do as a databases synchronizer from code using EF, then extract all the information from each of the tables in the database A and compared to information from the database B. This is the request.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the extension method I use in my EntityFramework Plus library.

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var dbSetProperties = ctx.GetDbSetProperties();
    List<object> dbSets = dbSetProperties.Select(x => x.GetValue(ctx, null)).ToList();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<PropertyInfo> GetDbSetProperties(this DbContext context)
    {
        var dbSetProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        var properties = context.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var setType = property.PropertyType;

#if EF5 || EF6
            var isDbSet = setType.IsGenericType && (typeof (IDbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(setType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) || setType.GetInterface(typeof (IDbSet<>).FullName) != null);
#elif EF7
            var isDbSet = setType.IsGenericType && (typeof (DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(setType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
#endif

            if (isDbSet)
            {
                dbSetProperties.Add(property);
            }
        }

        return dbSetProperties;

    }
}
```

**Edit**
You need to use reflection from the DbSet element type and iterate over all properties. This will not work with TPC, TPT and TPH

For a simpler solution, use the method GetModel from Entity Framework Extensions. This is a FREE feature of this library.

Project: [Entity Framework Extensions](http://www.zzzprojects.com/products/dotnet-development/entity-framework-extensions/)

Documentation: [GetModel](http://www.zzzprojects.com/support/documentations/net-entity-framework-extensions/#runtime-model-getmodel)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project Entity Framework Extensions

Comment: And how I can iterate through the properties of each table or DbSet?

Comment: The values in dbSets are not accessable even in iteration.
                List<object> dbSets = dbSetObjs.Select(x => x.GetValue(ctx, null)).ToList();
                foreach (var dbSet in dbSets)
                {
                    var obj = dbSet;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 EntityContainer container = ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
            List<string> result = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                      where meta.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntitySet
                      select meta.ElementType.ToString()).ToList<string>();
```