# SQL query a list of DBsets without knowing its specific type

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I have a List of DBsets and i need to go through all of these tables and find every row that has a specific ID.

```cs
db = new DBContext();
List<object> tables = new List<object> {
db.table1
db.table2
}
```

I though that i can iterate through all of the elements of the list and use .Where() Method but the problem is that i need to cast the object type into the specific type (DBSet)
something like this:

```cs
List<object> tables = new List<object> {
db.table1
db.table2
}
foreach (DBset<???> table in tables){
    table.Where(x => x.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

but as you can see above i don't know how to cast the object into the specific type because i dont know what type am i trying to use in that moment. So my question is how can I cast the variable into a specific type to use the .Where() method when i dont know what type it is?

Easy solution that I came up with was to get the type with the method .GetType() and after that create a switch with every table I have and hard code it, but the biggest problem with this solution is that when I add a new table, I will have to hardcode another table and I want to have it dynamic to work with any number of tables.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Some people asked my why do I need to do this:
The problem I am trying to solve is: I am creating an app with many "pages" every page has many inputs. whenever the user sets all the inputs and calls a specific action it has to save everything into a DB. I have to be able to load from the DB all the inputs and insert them into the app. every page is built from sections that are common for many pages - let's call them "UserElements". I created a table for every UserElement and save to them the inputs in them with a specific ID. Now I need to load from the DB everything that has that specific ID. The only things I know about what I need to load are the ID, and the page that I filled in to create this record. Based on this information I can get a list of every table used in that page - I get a list of every table that has something I need. This results in a list of DBsets I need to query to get everything I need to know.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Frow where list of `DbSet`s and for which purpose you want to filter it? Asking because looks like you are solving issue from wrong perspective.

Comment: This is an example of going over all the DbSet properties defined on a DbContext:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207159/how-to-get-all-dbset-from-dbcontext

Comment: I'm very curious how it can be interesting to know, for example, an Order having ID 321432 and a SecurityLog having that ID.  ID values tend to be meaningless. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269).

Answer (score 0):

One approach involves using the non-generic IQueryable interface and dynamically constructing LINQ expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
foreach (DbSet table in tables)
{
    DbSqlQuery query =  table.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table.GetType().Name + " WHERE ID = " + ID);
    foreach (var result in query)
    {
        foreach (var property in result.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(property.Name,result.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(result, null));
        }
    }
}
```

this code can execute any query in aby DBSet using the method SqlQuery() by using SQL query i can load the data i need from any table

Comment: How it is related to original question about filtering, ect.? This can be done without raw SQL. Also you have used wrong methods to retrieve metadata.

Comment: this code goes through every dbset in the tables list and writes out all values in rows that have specific ID. That is how it relates to the original question because that is what I was asking for. And I am not really sure it could be done without raw SQL but if you know how I would like to see it to know how to do it. What methods do i have wrong? this code works for me, and based on that i would assume that these methods are not wrong.

Comment: Change table name when configuring model and you will what I mean. Improve your question with sample classes (maybe they are derived from some common class) and probably I'll give you better solution.  This is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805899/10646316) for dumping all tables to CSV, simple change will do anything you want.